# If multiple cells are with the same text, return this text(value) to another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I need your help with this:

- If A1:E1 is "Red", return "Red" to C3;
- If A1:E1 is "Blue", return "Blue" to C3;

[image]

**BUT**

If A1:E1 are not the same, return False or "X" to C3

[image]

**What function to use here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(COUNTIF(A1:E1,A1)=5,A1,"X")`

5 means here the total number of cells, as suggested by Ahmed, it can also be counted by `COLUMNS(A1:E1)`, `COUNT(A1:E1)`...

Comment: It gives me an error :( What is the "5" there?

Comment: 5 means all the five cells has the same content? What is the error? In which language do you use Excel (you may need to replace `,` to `;`)?

Comment: Yes, it was language problem...Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:E1,A1)=COLUMNS(A1:E1),A1,"X")
```

you can define range by using `COLUMNS(A1:E1)` instead of manually counting `5` in above stated answer by @Máté Juhász